# React Native Navigation by Wix - bottomTabs not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add bottomTabs to my React Native app but it doesn't show and doesn't throw any errors at me. When I compile it, the "Hello World" text shows up perfectly and the topBar even works as it should, but I just can't get the bottomTabs working.

The Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View

} from 'react-native';

import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

const SavedScreen = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

Navigation.registerComponent('HomeScreen', () => HomeScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent('InfoScreen', () => InfoScreen);

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(async () =>{
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root:{
            bottomTabs: {
                id: 'BOTTOM_TABS_LAYOUT',
                children: [
                  {
                    stack: {
                      id: 'HOME_TAB',
                      children: [
                        {
                          component: {
                            id: 'HOME_SCREEN',
                            name: 'HomeScreen'
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          icon: require('../assets/images/home.png')
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    stack: {
                      id: 'SAVED_TAB',
                      children: [
                        {
                          component: {
                            id: 'SAVED_SCREEN',
                            name: 'SavedScreen'
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      options: {
                        bottomTab: {
                          icon: require('../assets/images/home.png')
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
        }
    })
})
export default SavedScreen;
```

I'm using React Native Navigation version 7.11.2